# Create a VIEW where a record in t1 is not present in t2 ? Confirmation on Union/Left Join/Inner Join?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a view of records in t1 where the source id from t1 is not in t2.

Like... "what records are not present in the other table?"

Do I need to include t2 in the FROM clause? Thanks

```
SELECT t1.fee_source_id, t1.company_name, t1.document
FROM t1
WHERE t1.fee_source_id NOT IN (

     SELECT t1.fee_source_id
     FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.fee_source_id = t2.fee_source

                              )
ORDER BY t1.aif_id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to effect an anti-join, for which there are three possibilities in MySQL:

1. Using `IN`:

   ```
   SELECT fee_source_id, company_name, document
   FROM   t1
   WHERE  fee_source_id NOT IN (SELECT fee_source FROM t2)
   ORDER BY aif_id DESC
   ```
2. Using `EXISTS`:

   ```
   SELECT fee_source_id, company_name, document
   FROM   t1
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.fee_source = t1.fee_source_id LIMIT 1
   )
   ORDER BY aif_id DESC
   ```
3. Using `JOIN`:

   ```
   SELECT   t1.fee_source_id, t1.company_name, t1.document
   FROM     t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.fee_source = t1.fee_source_id
   WHERE    t2.fee_source IS NULL
   ORDER BY t1.aif_id DESC
   ```

According to [@Quassnoi's analysis](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/):

> #### Summary
>
> MySQL can optimize all three methods to do a sort of `NESTED LOOPS ANTI JOIN`.
>
> It will take each value from `t_left` and look it up in the index on `t_right.value`. In case of an index hit or an index miss, the corresponding predicate will immediately return `FALSE` or `TRUE`, respectively, and the decision to return the row from `t_left` or not will be made immediately without examining other rows in `t_right`.
>
> However, these three methods generate three different plans which are executed by three different pieces of code. The code that executes `EXISTS` predicate is about **30%** less efficient than those that execute `index_subquery` and `LEFT JOIN` optimized to use `Not exists` method.
>
> That’s why the best way to search for missing values in **MySQL** is using a `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` or `NOT IN` rather than `NOT EXISTS`.

However, I'm not entirely sure how this analysis reconciles with the MySQL manual section on [Optimizing Subqueries with `EXISTS` Strategy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html) which (to my reading) suggests that the second approach above should be *more efficient* than the first.

Answer (score 0):

Another option below (similar to anti-join)... Great answer above though. Thanks!

```
 SELECT   D1.deptno, D1.dname
        FROM     dept D1
        MINUS
        SELECT   D2.deptno, D2.dname
        FROM     dept D2, emp E2
        WHERE    D2.deptno = E2.deptno
        ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:mysql], which doesn't support the `MINUS` operator.